# Session Expire And Decrease User Status

Tags: php, session

I was create user auth and limitation login (just 2 user can login in same time ) and all of things is right 
But when ever session cookie was die ( after x time ) , users_status ( in database ) do not change ( decrease -1 ) 
It's meant : 
1 - Two Users Login To Website

> session_set_cookie_params(60,"/"); // 1 Minutes

2 - If User click on Logout ( it's fine ) 
but if user waiting and session was die , ( user actuley in database is not logout ) 
is there any way to decrease-1 users_status in database !?

Thanks for your helps and sorry for my poor :( english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any cookie expires, a server will not know about it. You can store active sessions in your database or with some caching solution (like memcache) with life times (TTLs). Then you can have a cron job, which checks all expired sessions (for instance, once per minute) and will decrease everything that must be decreased.

Comment: thanks and my last question is , did session update after website refresh ?

Comment: A session is detected by a session ID that is stored in cookies. If cookie is expired, it will be not sent to a server. So, you will get a totally new session without any link to the old one.

Comment: hmm thanks alot, i found some idea for that thanks again :*